# InfluxDB: How to create a continuous query to calculate delta values?

Tags: influxdb

I'd like to calculate the delta values for a series of measurements stored in an InfluxDB. The values are readings from an electricity meter taken every 5 minutes. The values increase over time. Here is subset of the data to give you an idea (commands shown below are executed in the InfluxDB CLI):

```
> SELECT "Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt" FROM "myhome_measurements" WHERE time >= '2018-02-02T10:00:00Z' AND time < '2018-02-02T11:00:00Z'
name: myhome_measurements
time                           Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt
----                           --------------------------
2018-02-02T10:00:12.610811904Z 11725.638
2018-02-02T10:05:11.242021888Z 11725.673
2018-02-02T10:10:10.689827072Z 11725.707
2018-02-02T10:15:12.143326976Z 11725.736
2018-02-02T10:20:10.753357056Z 11725.768
2018-02-02T10:25:11.18448512Z  11725.803
2018-02-02T10:30:12.922032896Z 11725.837
2018-02-02T10:35:10.618788096Z 11725.867
2018-02-02T10:40:11.820355072Z 11725.9
2018-02-02T10:45:11.634203904Z 11725.928
2018-02-02T10:50:11.10436096Z  11725.95
2018-02-02T10:55:10.753853952Z 11725.973
```

Calculating the differences in the InfluxDB CLI is pretty straightforward with the `difference()` function. This gives me the electricity consumed within the 5 minutes intervals:

```
> SELECT difference("Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt") FROM "myhome_measurements" WHERE time >= '2018-02-02T10:00:00Z' AND time < '2018-02-02T11:00:00Z'
name: myhome_measurements
time                           difference
----                           ----------
2018-02-02T10:05:11.242021888Z 0.03499999999985448
2018-02-02T10:10:10.689827072Z 0.033999999999650754
2018-02-02T10:15:12.143326976Z 0.02900000000045111
2018-02-02T10:20:10.753357056Z 0.0319999999992433
2018-02-02T10:25:11.18448512Z  0.03499999999985448
2018-02-02T10:30:12.922032896Z 0.033999999999650754
2018-02-02T10:35:10.618788096Z 0.030000000000654836
2018-02-02T10:40:11.820355072Z 0.03299999999944703
2018-02-02T10:45:11.634203904Z 0.028000000000247383
2018-02-02T10:50:11.10436096Z  0.02200000000084401
2018-02-02T10:55:10.753853952Z 0.02299999999922875
```

Where I struggle is getting this to work in a continuous query. Here is the command I used to setup the continuous query:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_Haushaltstromzaehler_cnt ON myhomedb 
BEGIN
    SELECT difference(sum("Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt")) AS "delta" INTO "Haushaltstromzaehler_delta" FROM "myhome_measurements" GROUP BY time(1h)
END
```

Looking in the InfluxDB log file I see that no data is written in the new 'delta' measurement from the continuous query execution:

```
...finished continuous query cq_Haushaltstromzaehler_cnt, 0 points(s) written...
```

After much troubleshooting and experimenting I now understand why no data is generated. Setting up a continuous query requires to use the `GROUP BY time()` statement. This in turn requires to use an aggregate function within the `differences()` function. The problem now is that the aggregate function returns only one value for the time period specified by `GROUP BY time()`. Obviously, the `differences()` function cannot calculate a difference from just one value. Essentially, continuous query executes a command like this:

```
> SELECT difference(sum("Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt")) FROM "myhome_measurements" WHERE time >= '2018-02-02T10:00:00Z' AND time < '2018-02-02T11:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h)
>
```

I'm now somewhat clueless as to how to make this work and appreciate any advice you might have.

Comment: I forgot to mention: this is with InfluxDB version 1.4.2

Comment: Maybe this could help, use `cumulative_sum` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604913/1052261

Answer (score 1):

Does it help using the last aggregate function? Not tested this as a cq yet.

```
Select difference(last(T1_Consumed)) AS T1_Delta, difference(last(T2_Consumed)) AS T2_Delta
from P1Data
where time >= 1551648871000000000 group by time(1h)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DIFFERENCE()` [would calculate delta from the "aggregated" value taken from *previous* group, not *within* current group.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/functions/#advanced-syntax-2)

So fill free to use selector function there - since your counters seemed to be cumulative, `LAST()` should be working well.

Comment: This didn't work. Here the InfluxQL statement that is being executed by the continuous query (CQ): `SELECT difference(last("Haushaltstromzaehler - cnt")) FROM "myhome_measurements" WHERE time >= '2017-12-01T10:00:00Z' AND time < '2017-12-01T11:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h)`. The problem is that "_When the CQ executes, it runs a single query for the time range between now() and **now() minus the GROUP BY time() interval**._". On the CLI I can specify a `WHERE` clause with time range that is larger than the GROUP BY time() interval. This is what generates the previous group. I can't do this in a CQ.